# Window transitions in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm doing a GUI in PyQt and I'm trying to do a transition between two windows. I tried through the following code and it doesn't works. I'm sure that I'm making a mistake but I don't know how to correct it?

```
def TransButton(self):
    win1 = AddWindow() (another class)
    win1.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a new window with no parent. As such, when you `TransButton` method ends, the `win1` variable is garbage collected (deleted) because neither Python or the Qt library are holding a reference to it (Qt would if it had a parent)

The quickest way to solve this is to change your code to something like:

```
def TransButton(self):
    self.win1 = AddWindow() (another class)
    self.win1.show()
```

where you store the `win1` variable as an instance attribute. This prevents `win1` from being garbage collected (and this the window being deleted) as long as the instance containing `TransButton` still exists.